# Kotlin: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am looping through an Array List and am getting thrown this error

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

Here is the Code

```kotlin
for(i in chatMessages.indices) {
    if(i < chatMessages.size){
   if(chatMessages[i] == "To" && chatMessages[i+1] != "To") {
     lastItem = true
 }}
 }
```

The Error is occurring with the following condition

```kotlin
chatMessages[i] == "To" && chatMessages[i+1] != "To"
```

Here is the array declaration

```kotlin
var chatMessages = arrayListOf<String>()
```

Why is my condition `i < chatMessages.size` not working?

Any help would be great

~ Matthew M

Comment: That `i+1` should ring a bell...

Comment: @forpas Sorry, What?

Comment: `i+1` never exists for the last element. Index is `0,1,2` for a list of size 3, index `3` never exist there.

Comment: `chatMessages[i+1]` is the next of the current item in each iteration. When your loop reaches the last item there is no next item and this is why the error is thrown.

Comment: @forpas Yes I understand that but I want to know why my `i < chatMessages.size` is not working. Sorry I formatted the question wrong

Comment: Change it to `i < chatMessages.size - 1`. Also, you might want a fold instead

Comment: Go for `if (i < chatMessages.lastIndex)`, that lastIndex is equivalent to `chatMessages.size-1` and looks more readable.

Comment: The indices of the list are 0 based. So the 1st item has index = 0.

Comment: I'd also point that `i in chatMessages.indices` already implies `i < chatMessages.size`, so the check there is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you check for `i < chatMessages.size`, you are trying to access `[i + 1]th` element that is not present. Change the `if` statement to `size-1` or should be less than the `lastIndex`

```
for (i in chatMessages.indices) {
  if (i < chatMessages.lastIndex) {
    if (chatMessages[i] == "To" && chatMessages[i + 1] != "To") {
      lastItem = true
    }
  }
}
```

Better solution with immutable variable and functional approach

```
val lastItem = chatMessages.zipWithNext()
    .any { it.first == "To" && it.second != "To" }
```